# Dereference Operator when using with argv[i]

Tags: c, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get why asterisk sign need when using `isdigit()` and why asterisk sign is not needed when using `atoi()`

Comment: Read the [isdigit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) and [atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) man pages. What are the types of the arguments to each?

Comment: FYI, `isdigit(*argv[1])` should be `isdigit((unsigned char) *argv[1])`, because the C standard does not guarantee that `isdigit` works for a `char` except for a base set of characters.

Answer (score 4):

`argv[1]` is a string, and so `*argv[1]` is the first character in the string.  Same thing as `argv[1][0]`.  Calling `isdigit(*argv[1])` therefore checks if the first character in the string is a digit.

That test is being used to check if the argument is (probably) a number, after which the entire string is passed into `atoi()` to get the whole value.